# How should I translate 属地化？

Tags: meaning

In my text I have 2 sentences with 属地化。‘属地化管理’ is a phrase which can be easily found in 百度。 Does it have more connotations than 'regional management'? '属地‘ seems to mean 'dependency', as in a region which is dependent on a geographically separate area, such as a colony， so it has more meaning than '地区‘ or '区域性’. Is it ok to translate '属地化‘ just as 'regional'？ I suppose 'regional management' implies an overarching 'central management'.

于是我们开始按照全新的属地化原则来管理海外市场， 也就是说，我们每到一地， 除了财务管理有集团外拍人员控制外，市场建设和网络维护人员均从当地招聘产生。

and

属地化的人才建立以后，集团的市场开拓出现了怎样的局面？

于是我们开始按照全新的属地化原则来管理海外市场

Thus, we began to manage our overseas markets according to the new 'regional management principle', ....

属地化的人才建立以后

After having set up regional personnel,

Comment: 'Localization'?

Comment: Basically, the first sentence says it all: apart from the finance and accounting, which stays under central control, they appoint native staff of whatever country, who can deal with their compatriots well, without culture related problems. Put that in one or two words!

Comment: Again. Pleco. Oxford: localize [sample sentence]: 属地化管理 localized management

Comment: Bit of a jump from 'dependency -ize' to 'localize', wouldn't you agree? Ideas are being misinterpreted. Can pleco ever be wrong?

Comment: @Pedroski it's Oxford, Oxford obviously is not perfect, but I wouldn't hesitate to not put my money on Oxford.

Comment: I don't like local because we are not talking about a particular place, a town or even a county, but entire countries, where this Chinese 跨国企业 has established branches and decided to employ 100% nationals of whatever land, except for the finance side of things, which stays in Chinese hands. For instance, the US of A. 'I'm in local management.' 'In which locality do you operate?‘ ‘Oh, the US.' A country the size of China can hardly be called a locality. Maybe 'territorial management' is better.

Answer (score 2):

There is an article on [属地原则](http://www.baike.com/wiki/%E5%B1%9E%E5%9C%B0%E5%8E%9F%E5%88%99) at 互动百科. It seems to be some variation of the territoriality principle, but that's public international law, and I've found several places where it's used to talk about regional versus national authority. Hard to say how to translate if Chinese has adapted a word to its own purposes.

(Dang! Second paragraph got chopped off, added below; also a comment on the correct translation given in the comments above)

If you add a 化 -ize, 属地化 would apparently mean something like 'territorialize', definitely no colonial implications though. The [属地化管理](http://baike.baidu.com/view/2474826.htm) article at 百度 gives a bunch of odd definitions, including the transfer of geological surveys from the State Council to the provincial level, or the transfer of "family management" responsibilities to local authorities for the "mobile population".  None of this fits in very well with the examples given, which all involve overseas business.  Would "territorially based management" work?

## Localized management

As  user3306356 notes above, "localized management" is the correct translation. Quite interesting; "Localized management" on google leads to articles on control  of white-tailed deer, sinus and prostate problems, and apparently some kind of server-network controls. "Localization management" is mixed up with these, but that's all about translating stuff for international businesses.

When "localized management" in a business context does turn up, most of the references are to Chinese sources.  This looks like a case where Chinese has managed to establish a new usage in English. Can anyone find "localized management" in business that is not from China based sources?

Comment: google, as an arm of the NSA is better avoided, however nice they want to make your life.

Comment: I'll  keep that in mind. So you prefer 百度 to google?

Comment: I use any old search engine! If you are in China, pages with google ad links will load veeeryyy slowly. China blocks google. A way around this is find a file on your computer called hosts. Keep what's in it, but add lines like: 127.0.0.1 partner.googleadservices.com This makes the page you are loading look on your local machine for the link. It doesn't find it and moves on, instead of waiting for it to load. Just add lines for any link that takes a long time, ie all google links in China. Simple, but very effective. Works well with Linux, should work with Win too!